# How to count rows in SQL Server with range distinct to count the record within range

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT Distinct 
    m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskID,m_KioskInformationHdr.agency,
    m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskIP,
    COUNT(distinct m_KioskInformationHdr.KioskID) as NoDT
from
    m_KioskInformationHdr
inner join 
    t_KioskStatus ON t_kioskStatus.kioskID = m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskID
where
    t_KioskStatus.IsOpen = 1 
    and DatePost between '2014-01-20 00:00:00' and '2014-01-21 23:59:59'
group by 
    t_KioskStatus.DatePost, m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskID,
    m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskIP, m_KioskInformationHdr.agency
```

I want this output:

```
01254878 | PHilippines,Pasig | 192.168.2.8 | 2
```

This is my current output:

```
01254878 | PHilippines,Pasig | 192.168.2.8 | 1
01254878 | PHilippines,Pasig | 192.168.2.8 | 1
```

How can I do this query?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `t_KioskStatus.DatePost`? Are you trying to get the total sum of each instant-in-time's distinct count? (I say instant-in-time because it appears DatePost is a datetime)

Comment: Regardless many logs in one day i need to count that in 1 and if i search by range it will total the last column only i dont know what to do please help thanks

Comment: remove group by t_KioskStatus.DatePost

Comment: if you want any number of logs in one day count as one, then your count should count(distinct cast(t_KioskStatus.DatePost as date)). I'm assuming DatePost is datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
mk.kioskID, mk.agency, mk.kioskIP, count(mk.kioskID) as NoDT 
from   
( 
    SELECT
    m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskID,m_KioskInformationHdr.agency,m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskIP

    from  
        m_KioskInformationHdr
    inner join
        t_KioskStatus ON t_kioskStatus.kioskID = m_KioskInformationHdr.kioskID
    where
        t_KioskStatus.IsOpen = 1 
        and DatePost between '2014-01-20 00:00:00' and '2014-01-21 23:59:59') mk
    group by 
        mk.DatePost, mk.kioskID,
        mk.kioskIP, mk.agency
```